# SQL:How sum each columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select t.col1 a, t.col1+...+t.coln-1 b, t.col1+...+t.coln-1+t.coln c
from table
```

Can direct use `b+t.col3`?

I can think of:

```
with t1 as (select col1+...+coln-1 b from table)
select t2.col1 a, t1.b, t1.b+t2.coln c
from table t2
inner join t1 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Is there another way to do this.

Comment: Huh? Why are you looking for a different way? Is this some sort of interview question, or is there an actual reason for looking for a different way?

Comment: Your second way would work, but it would be very inefficient as it would scan the table twice AND require a join. Are you looking for ways to make it even much worse than that? Write it in a loop in a procedure, so each row is processed one at a time. Are you looking to make it more efficient? Use the first way you showed, which is the most efficient - it only scans the table once and there are no joins.

Comment: It is such,sometime the b is too long(more than 100 characters),I need to call when having to write one more time.Lead to SQL statement hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can also do it in this way .

```
select a, b, b+col3
from (
select t.col1 a, t.col1+t.col2 b, t.col3
from t)
```

Comment: You think wrong, and thinking so shows you know very little about SQL. (And therefore you shouldn't post answers without testing them first; when your answers are correct a few times, you can then start answering with untested solutions.) Definite downvote.

Comment: @mathguy - can you explain, without a patronising tone, what is wrong with this answer. I know a bit about sql and unless I am missing something subtle this looks ok to me.

Comment: @DaveRlz - **Sorry** - nothing is wrong with this solution, and my downvote is now removed. I am an idiot - I reacted without reading the full solution, and it seemed to me (incorrectly) that Hassan made the same mistake as the OP: using a name he had defined in SELECT for another expression in the same SELECT. Obviously he didn't do that, his solution is correct. Hassan: My apologies, I was wrong and unfair!

Comment: ... or actually there is something "wrong" with this solution, but nothing to do with my objection in the earlier comment. What is wrong is that it uses a subquery when it's not needed (selecting col1, col1+col2, col1+col2+col3 should be more efficient). Although the optimizer may be able to "see" that and rewrite the query that way. In any case, my first comment was 100% wrong.

Comment: I've used just this sort of technique in the past. For more complex cases where "col1" is actually an expression that is 200 characters long, and so is col2, and so is col3, etc, it works well. It's unfortunate that Oracle doesn't allow column aliases to be referenced in other columns as it would improve the readability and robustness of the code by respecting the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle.

Comment: You could also use a set of common table expressions to implement this, of course.

Comment: it's okay @mathguy

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT SUM(t.COL1) a, SUM(t.COL1 + t.COL2) b, SUM(t.COL1 + t.COL2 + t.COL3) c
FROM TABLE1 t
```

As mathguy mentioned below, you do not want to sum the columns and add totals, it was not so clear for me but now it make sense :)

```
SELECT t.COL1 a, t.COL1 + t.COL2 b, t.COL1 + t.COL2 + t.COL3 c
FROM TABLE1 t
```

will give you correct values.

Comment: There is no indication the OP wanted to calculate column totals - he is only looking to add values in each row, separately.

Comment: @mathguy - the question is titled 'SQL:How sum each columns in oracle' - that seem to state an intention, whether or not it is what was actually required is a different matter.

Comment: @DaveRlz - yes, I thought so too when I read the title, then I read the actual question and realized the OP wanted to add across columns, not down columns. That is what I tried to communicate to the responder here, with my comment above. I meant it as an explanation, not as criticism, I hope it didn't come across the wrong way.